# Как защитить свои исходники от использования третьими лицами? C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

Пишу программу для диплома. Хоть я программист слабый и зеленый, но уже смог написать пару интересных штук по распознаванию. Случился такой треш:
Научный руководитель, который ведет меня к диплому(которому я для демонстрации скинул как дурак весь проект в visual studio) просто отдал другому своему студенту мои исходники и написали тезис уже по ним с другим студентом(без меня в авторстве).
Скидывать программу с кодами я обязан. Просто exe шником не отделаться. Как мне защитить свою работу, при этом скидывая код научнику? Прошу совета опытных коллег=)

Comment: И как вы в этой ситуации пострадали? Не очень понятно, от чего собственно вы собираетесь защищаться. "отдал другому своему студенту мои исходники" - ну выкладывайте их первым в публичный доступ с соотв. лицензией.

Comment: Используйте обфускацию кода.

Comment: У меня программа распознавания белых квадратов без opencv и т п занимает несколько 3-4 листиков А4. Я не считаю что там что-то особенное - тупо статистика, анализ, куча ветвлений. Если кто сопрет - не огорчусь вообще. Возможно лет через 5 вы скажете сами - списали - ну и хз)))) Могу добавить, что у каждого человека свой почерк. Списаную работу - руководитель увидит сразу. Списавшие как правило получают оценку ниже. Постарайтесь не обращать на такие вещи внимание, лучше уделите времени своему развитию или отдыху.

Comment: Если вы пишите на с++ - почитайте про `#define`, можно поставить опции компилятора, и через `#define` протянуть их в програму так, что без определенных ключей компиляции - код не соберётся. Да и вообще `#define` позволяет максимально весело запутать код.

Comment: Смысл в том, что сам кирпич диплома я пишу сам. Без его помощи. Он просит только программу. Суть в том, чтобы я успел тезисы написать по проделанной работе и опубликовать.

Comment: Мне посоветовали использовать внешнюю dll библиотеку(туда вынести весь свой код, который нужно временно изолировать от глаз)

Comment: Да, можно и так - внешняя библиотека.

Comment: "Он просит только программу" - ну так не давайте ее, если от него никакого прока, зачем вы связались с таким руководителем? Вообще какая-то мутная ситуация. Интересно было бы послушать ее с другой стороны баррикад, а то как-то больно сильный перекос.

Comment: Мой бывший научный руководитель уволился. Меня перевели к этому научруку. Он мне сразу сказал "твои сроки, твой диплом - всё это твои проблемы, на тебя времени нет, у меня свои студенты". Спустя год моей самостоятельной работы и публикации двух тезисов отдельно от него он начал требовать исходники. Я понимаю что научруков загружают по самое небалуй и ему доп проблемы не нужны. Но использовать чужое, без авторства, без ведома, без вообще разговора об этом - неккоректно и неэтично.

Comment: Ссора с руководителем - риск несдать. Оно вам надо? Если руководитель недалёкий (что редкость) можно схитрить через dll. это определенный риск. Мне кажется - сдавайте нормально диплом, и не обращайте внимание. Мне кажется написать сдать забыть и всё. Если в хороших отношениях с деканом/зам декана, и есть возможность сменить руководителя - можете поговорить с деканом.

Comment: Разве дипломы сделанные в универе не принадлежат тому самому университету?

Comment: Правильная стратегия нападения - сообщить руководителю, попытаться договориться с ним. Если не выйдет - деканат. Но желательно заранее знать были такие случаи или нет, увереность что есть другой руководитель, и что деканат пойдёт вам на встречу. Скандал конечно не лучшее решение. Если ваша работа используется - то если третья сторона обнаружит dll - то вам скажут что вы нечесны. В случае с `#define FALSE true` вы будете выглядеть шутником, и меньше шансов что вас обвинят в нечесности. Возможности #define столь широки, что можно сокращать целые блоки программы и потом сложно распутать.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это вопрос не по программированию, а по конфликтной ситуации с руководителем дипломного проекта.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы обязаны скинуть программу с исходниками, значит ваш научный руководитель в любом случае ее посмотрит. И сможет сделать с ними все, что хочет.

Конкретно в вашем случае - не советую делать какие-то защиты, пишите диплом, защищайте его и радуйтесь волшебной корочке.

А для общего развития на эту тему почитайте про обфускацию, хотя бы [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/122807/). Но главное - **любую защиту можно взломать**. Вопрос в соотношении цена/необходимость.

Comment: Ага, обфусцировать код, принцип работы которого разъясняется в дипломном проекте. Ссылка вообще не в тему.

Comment: я же написал, что ссылка для общего развития по теме. А про дипломный проект - прочитайте все, что выше ссылки.